# T4 markup syntax meanings?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, t4

In ASP.NET (`*.aspx` and `*.tt`) what is the meaning of the following markups: `<#= #>` `<# #>` `<#+ #>`?

Comment: What did you not understand in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126478)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The markup you describe in your question has nothing to do with ASP.NET.  They are examples of T4 template markup syntax.  T4 templates are transformed within Visual Studio and can be used to create any type of file, [although most commonly they are used for code generation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx).

`<#= #>` executes the code within the markup and returns the text result.  Example:

```
// in this example, TargetNamespace is set to "MuhNamespace"
namespace <#= this.TargetNamespace #> { // outputs: namespace MuhNamespace
```

`<# #>` executes the code within but returns `void`.  Example:

```
This collection contains the following foos:
<#foreach(var foo in bar){ #>
    <#= foo.Name + Environment.NewLine #>
<# } #>
```

`<#+ #>` define reusable methods that can be called within the template.  For example,

```
This collection contains the following types:
<#foreach(var foo in bar){ #>
    <#= GetType(foo) #>
<# } #>

<#+  public string GetType(foo){ return foo.GetType().FullName; } #>
```

there are more of these as well, examples of which [can be found here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff697256.aspx)